# How to make column of ascending numbers consecutive?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with a column of repeating numbers in ascending order. How can I modify the column so that the ascending numbers become also consecutive?

I have tried a list comprehension across rows, but I need a column operation for fast performance.

```
d = {'col1': [1,1,1,2,2,4,4,7,7,7,50,50]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df1

  col1
0   1
1   1
2   1
3   2
4   2
5   4
6   4
7   7
8   7
9   7
10  50
11  50
```

need the following output:

```
 col1 col2
0   1   1
1   1   1
2   1   1
3   2   2
4   2   2
5   4   3
6   4   3
7   7   4
8   7   4
9   7   4
10  50  5
11  50  5
```

Comment: or  `df1['new_col']=(~df1.col1.duplicated()).cumsum()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`pd.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html):

```
df1['col2'] = pd.factorize(df1.col1)[0] + 1

     col1  col2
0      1     1
1      1     1
2      1     1
3      2     2
4      2     2
5      4     3
6      4     3
7      7     4
8      7     4
9      7     4
10    50     5
11    50     5
```